# How to fix test code error: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null?

Tags: apex

Here is my trigger, class, and test code. Why is my test code not passing?

System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.
Class.LocationUpdateReferral.updateCreatedLocationsonReferral: line 13, column 1

**Trigger**

```
trigger LocationTrigger on Location__c (after update) {
    for (Location__c loc : trigger.new){
        if ( (trigger.oldMap.get(loc.Id).status__c != 'Lost' && loc.Status__c == 'Lost') || (trigger.oldMap.get(loc.Id).status__c != 'Denied' && loc.Status__c == 'Denied')){
            id refId;
            string facility;
            if (loc.Referral__c != null && loc.Location__c != null){
                refId = loc.Referral__c;
                facility = loc.Location__r.name;
                Set<string> locationNameSet = new Set<string>();
                locationNameSet.add(facility);
            LocationUpdateReferral.updateCreatedLocationsonReferral(refId, locationNameSet );
        }    
        }
}
}
```

**Class**

```
public class LocationUpdateReferral {
@future (callout = true)
    public static void updateCreatedLocationsonReferral(id refId, set<string> facility){
        
        lead ref = [select id, All_Locations_Hidden__c from lead where id = : refId];
        
        if (ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c != null){
            
            for (string loc : facility){
                string semiFirst = ';' + loc;
                string semiLast = loc + ';';
                
                if (ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c.contains(loc)){
                    ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c =  ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c.remove(loc);
                }
                else if (ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c.contains(loc)){
                    ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c =  ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c.remove(loc);
                }
            }
            update ref;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@isTest
public class LocationCLeadHandlerTest {
    
    static testMethod void refTestMethod(){
        Id facilityAccountid = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Facility Account').getRecordTypeId();
        Account a = new Account(name = 'Essex Center', recordtypeid = facilityAccountid);
        insert a;

        date d = date.today();
        Lead l = new Lead(firstname = 'John', lastname = 'Smith', patient_dob__c = d, insurancecompany__c = acc.id, All_Locations_Hidden__c = 'Essex Center;');
        insert l;
        
        Location__c loc = new Location__c (referral__c = l.id, location__c = a.Id);
        insert loc;
        
        loc = [select id, status__c, denial_lost_reason__c from location__c where id = :loc.id];
        loc.Status__c = 'Lost';
        loc.Denial_Lost_Reason__c = 'Other SNF';
        update loc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            facility = loc.Location__r.name;
            Set<string> locationNameSet = new Set<string>();
            locationNameSet.add(facility);
```

Triggers don't have access to relational data. `loc.Location__r.Name` is `null`. You have to query for relationship data you want to access in a trigger.

`NullPointerException` is one of the rare instances where the error really doesn't lie or deceive you. It always means that something is `null`. That means that resolving it is simply a matter of following the `null` value back from the error to its source.

Comment: Additionally, we can know that this is the issue because your error was _argument cannot be null_. Meaning `loc` is null on line 13 (`ref.All_Locations_Hidden__c.contains(loc)`). Debugging NPEs is usually an exercise in deduction (determining what can possibly be null, and then working backwards to find out where the null came from).

Comment: Thank you for that information this helped solve the issue